# List with max-height in smartphone

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to know how to give a max-height to `<div>` or `<ul>` elements.

I have this:

```
<div id="list1">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-gorup-item">item1</li>
      <li class="list-gorup-item">item2</li>
      <li class="list-gorup-item">item3</li>
      <li class="list-gorup-item">item4</li>
      <li class="list-gorup-item">item5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this CSS media:

```
@media (max-width: 480px){
   #list1{
       max-height: 10%;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.  Also, must it appear on scroll?

EDIT:

Hi, accomplish it work, using overflow: auto; and "px" :

```
@media (max-width: 480px){
   #list1{
       overflow: auto;
       max-height: 150px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate with `overflow: hidden|auto|...`
Maybe you want to set maximum height for your content to scaling?
How you want it to behave when height of list exceeds defined height?